# How to - loading properties files with formatted sql in them?

Tags: java, sql, properties-file

My application needs to have queries externalized, so to make use of default resourcebundle, I've decided to go with queries in properties files. So, here's what a properties file looks like now:

```
SELECT_USER_QUERY = Select username, userid from user where userid=?

INSERT_USER_QUERY = insert into user values (?,?)
```

The problem here obviously is not a showstopper - this properties file gets picked up and gets processed nicely, but for somebody to edit in the near future, it looks ugly. I would like something like this:

```
SELECT_USER_QUERY = select username, userid
                    from user
                    where userid=?
```

I want to see that formatting in my properties file. I think one way to go about it would be to introduce a "\" (as per some answers on SO) at the end of each line. Are there any other ways to retain formatting in the properties file and still load it successfully?

Comment: you can use  "\" - that's true. however you may want to use XML instead. also there are a number of mapping framework (ibatis for example) which allows you to externalize SQLs

Comment: Have you thought about XML file for queries?

Comment: no - I would like to avoid XML. Way too much complexity for a simple task like this.

Comment: My program is not so complicated that it needs ORM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I think one way to go about it (and most likely I would) is to write all queries in a properties file, but each query value spanning multiple formatted rows. I will be using a custom ResourceBundle to load these properties in a custom way. This way, I can ensure that there is formatting in properties file and also code wise load properties using ResourceBundle.

Answer (score 3):

Just add a \ at the end of the line, that must not be interpreted as a linebreak.
There is no other way to retain the formatting (line breaks) in a properties file

Comment: Ok. The chances of missing a link break are pretty high and that wouldn't pop up until that query is tested. I think I will need something better.

Answer (score 2):

There's no reason to restrict yourself to properties files. Why not simply store the above in a text file and have (say) a text file per query/statement ? That way someone can edit the text file without having to worry about properties-style formatting.

Comment: This is an option I am considering right now. But one text file per query will result in too many text files - I would like to avoid that situation.